# How do I prove that the trace is contained in this set?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow G$ be a closed rectifiable curve.

Define $H=\{z\in G\setminus \gamma([0,1]): Wnd(\gamma,z)\neq 0\}$

I have proven that $cl(H)\subset G$ and $cl(H)$ is compact.

Is it true that $\gamma([0,1])\subset cl(H)$?

If $\gamma$ is a simple close curve, then it is true. However, is it true for general rectifiable curves?

Comment: Shouldn't $\gamma$ lie inside of $G$ for $cl(H)$ to be inside of $G$?

Comment: @dafinguzman right edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace of $\gamma$ is not necessarily contained in the closure of $H$. A simple example is

$$\gamma(t) = \bigl\lvert \tfrac{1}{2} - t\bigr\rvert.$$

This is a rectifiable (it's piecewise continuously differentiable even) closed curve, and $H = \varnothing$ for this curve. More generally, if $\gamma$ enters into a region where the winding number is $0$ and then tracks back on its trace, such a spike would not be in the closure of $H$. The same if the trace crosses the entire component $C$ of the region with, then loops enclosing another region, and then tracks back on its trace through $C$.

If no such things happen, then the trace is contained in the closure of $H$, since on all simple parts<sup>(1)</sup> of the trace, the winding numbers in the regions on the left and on the right of the trace differ by one, so at least in one of the regions, it is nonzero.

<sup>(1)</sup> Intentionally left imprecise, since a precise characterisation of the situation is involved.

Comment: Good points! However, my impression is that the OP was after a proof for the case where it is true.

Comment: @DanielFischer Would you please check my new post? It is very related to this one.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464039/counting-finite-zeros-among-infinite-zeros